# TFS Release - Deployment - How to schedule deploy AFTER release created?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to schedule each deploy for each environment after the release record has been created?

The problem we have is we create a release and have DEV, UAT, STAGE, and PROD environments.  However we do not know when each deploy will happen.

Management wants STAGE and PROD to be deployed on a timestamp, not manually.  The UI only seems to allow this from net new releases.

We won't know the prod or stage deploy schedule until AFTER we create the release and DEV/UAT are signed off.

How can I schedule STAGE and PROD after the fact?

We currently run TFS on Prem 2017 Update 3.

EDIT: I just tried in vsts (Azure DevOps now) with the latest and it appears to not offer this feature with the latest build either.

This seems like something VERY obvious that would be needed.

I have builds ready.  I have a release record made, and I want to SCHEDULE these builds to deploy at a certain time.  I cannot do it.  I have to cut a NEW build and schedule the Release instead.

This is just nuts.

Answer (score 2):

When you submit a pre-deployment approval for a stage, you can defer the deployment until a specified time.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is close to what I was looking for.  Still an awkward workaround at best.  Thank you! :D

Answer (score 1):

The latest on Azure DevOps let's you define a scheduled time for release.

[image]

Comment: That is BEFORE the release is cut yes.  What I am looking for is the flexibility to add a schedule AFTER the release record gets cut.  We don't know the exact date/time of deployment to every step before we start to run through the pipeline.  We need the flexibility to schedule each deploy step after the release gets cut.

Comment: And that is why deferred approvals exist? You can either pre-schedule the deployment as per this answer or if you want to do it later then defer to another time.

Comment: One question. This option will trigger the deployment every Monday at that time, right? What if I wanted to deploy only once?